# How do I form a dictionary with words from given files?

Tags: scripts, dictionary

How do I extract all words from all files in a given directory in order to make a dictionary? The words must be different from each other(letters in caps are not taken into consideration. For example, car=Car), they will be written with small letters in the dictionary(even if in originally they had caps), they will be sorted alphabetically and each line in the dictionary will contain only one word. The dictionary will be in /home/dictionary.txt.

Comment: It depends greatly on the format of the files that will be read to create the dictionary. Are they one word a line, words separated by commas or ; or <>.... Please give an example.

Comment: the words are extracted from a random text. For example, from "mom, dad and my brother went home." we should extract only "mom dad and my brother went home". Basicly, we only have to keep a continuous string of characters from a-z or A-Z. Any other type of character should be discarded.

Comment: So if "Superman2K came to my home and fought Spiderman3D" Then it should extract superman came to my home and fought spiderman" or without supermand and spiderman beause of the numbers.

Comment: Doesn't this really belong on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ or similar?

Comment: That is the exact text it should extract(including spiderman and superman), except the words have to be sorted alphabetically.

Comment: You can pipe data to `uniq` to skip duplicate word entries. So you don't get the same word if it occurs more than once.

Answer (score 1):

johnny, I think what you want to do could easy be done in a bash script. But you are going to want to study up on redirection, input files... ; [should get you going hopefully.](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-redirecting-input-multiple-files) 
| [For getting words or patterns...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257432/bash-is-that-string-only-containing-a-z-a-z-and-0-9)

Answer (score 0):

Depends heavily on the contents of the directory, but... this should be at least a very good start if we are talking about plain text files in the directory in question.

```
cd
find $directory_name -type f -exec grep -o -E '\w+' {} \; | sort -u -f > out
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < out > dictionary.txt
rm out
```

About the switches, `man $command` can expound.

Remove numbers: `sed 's/[0-9]*//g' dictionary.txt > a_different_file`

Remove blank lines: `sed '/^$/d' dictionary.txt > some_other_file`

Comment: There is a problem with this solution. Apart from returning words from the given files, it also returns numbers. What do you think I should modify?

Comment: Yeah... a good start depending on what you have. See updated answer. rdh said it plainly on the learning curve...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with awk

```
 awk 'BEGIN {RS=" "}; /^[A-Za-z]*$/ {print tolower ($0)}' ./* | sed 's_[.].*$__g' | sort -u
```

"print tolower" simply converts to all lower case (makes sort -u work).

The sed removes trailing periods, you may or may not need to manage other symbols depending on your input files.

Comment: I still don't get the desired output. I need to extract all continuous strings of characters that contain only letters from a-z  or A-Z(which have to be transformed into small letters) and then sort them alphabetically and put them in a different file.

Comment: awk uses regular expressions `awk 'BEGIN {RS=" "}; /^[A-Za-z]*$/ {print tolower ($0)}' ./* | sed 's_[.].*$__g' | sort -u`

Comment: Now I have some words missing.

Comment: Well, we can only get you so far. You will need to read up on regular expressions, look at the output, and revise. Perhaps run through the files in steps. But it is impossible for us to write an exact script without examining the data and knowing exactly what you want , what is missing, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to adapt the script to exactly fit my needs.